# Общие настройки для разных приложений

Tags: android

Добрый день всем.
Как можно сделать общий настройки для разных приложений.
Допустим в первом приложении ставим настройку.
И чтобы другое приложение могло ее считать?

Answer (score 3):

Существует [ряд методов](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) по работе с данными из приложения:

- Shared Preferences
- Internal Storage
- External Storage
- SQLite Databases
- Network Connection

Из них только External Storage позволяет обращаться к данным из разных приложений. Поэтому можно поступить так: создать приложение, которое будет управлять настройками группы приложений, и обеспечить доступ к этим настройкам для других приложений, сделав его [Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html#basics)'ом.

Answer (score 0):

А еще настройки можно хранить в облаке.